# How import pdf files from assets folder in Nx monorepo ( react )

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, nomachine-nx

I have an nx monorepo with a project that has a folder of assets with pdf files inside, but for some reason I can't import them because the environment just doesn't see them. What do I need to do to import the pdf files?

For now I get next error when trying import pdf file in app component
like this

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './assets/pdf.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I suppose I need some kind of webpack config to fix it in the root of the project? But it's weird that Nx doesn't care about this